# Call professor without using the name

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I just attended to a study project in abroad and I don't know if I'm correct at calling people and professors.

Is it possible to call a professor just only "professor"?

I mean, is it possible to not use any first name or last name. For example, when I see one of my professor, I say him " Hello professor" and don't greet him as " Hello professor Thompson".

Is this appropriate and normal?

Thanks

Comment: It might be worth adding where you are. This is likely to depend a lot on where you are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is acceptable and common to address people who have a title, position, or rank with a title, by their title alone, e.g. "Hello, nurse/doctor/professor/judge/mayor/captain/Prime Minister (etc)".

Comment: Might mention that this is intentionally impersonal.  It maintains professional distance and respect.

Comment: @Michael Harvey and James K thank you both for your answer ;-)

Comment: My reaction (for which I don't have any evidence to hand) is that this only applies when using a title, not just a position; if someone's called ‘Professor Jones’, then it's common to call them ‘Professor’, but you wouldn't address e.g. a bus driver in that way.  If so, I think this answer might be clearer if ‘Nurse/Doctor/…’ were capitalised.

Comment: @gidds Positions are often used when you need to directly address someone but don't know their name. One example I hear often is "Back door please, Driver!" called out from the back of a bus when they've closed the door too early.

Comment: In Britain, it is common, when passing the driver to leave a bus, to thank him or her, and where I live (Bristol) many people say "Thank you, driver!"

Comment: @JamesK I don’t agree that this is impersonal. If you know your professor well (but study at an institution where students and professors are not on a first-name basis), “Good morning, professor” seems far **less** formal and distant than “Good morning, Professor Thompson”. Unless you were saying it’s impersonal compared to using a name without a title – then I agree, of course.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Is this the same for writing? In letter, for example. Greetings as "Hello Doctor" or "Hi professor".